# Sencha Touch on WP8: Focus on textfield doesn't show soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

I have a requirement in my app to dynamically focus on the textfield when the page loads.
I have tried some workarounds as mentioned below

1.)

```
Ext.getCmp('idTextFocus').focus();
```

I have also tried to focus in a timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    Ext.getCmp('idTextFocus').focus();
},1000);
```

2.) Created an input text inside html

```
{
    html:'<input type="text" id="idTextFocus1" />'
}
```

In painted function i have written

```
document.getElementById('idTextFocus1').focus();
```

I have also tried to give a time out function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('idTextFocus1').focus();
},1000);
```

I am using Sencha Touch 2.2 and Phonegap, i have also tried with the latest sencha touch version but could'nt get it working.

Can i write some Phonegap plugin to forcefully open the keyboard or is there any piece of code to fix this particular Sencha Touch issue.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you calling the `focus()` method? In [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6np) it's working calling it in the `activate`of the parent view.

Do you see the cursor blink on the field? If you see it, then the problem is not with `focus()` but with the softkeyboard which is not showing up. If that is the problem then you should go with a Phonegap plugin like https://github.com/mamonth/cordova-plugin-softkeyboard to force it appearing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anubis.Yes,the cursor blinks but the keyboard does not show up. We are developing this application for Windows Phone 8, is it possible to force show the keyboard in Windows Phone 8 by writing a Phonegap plugin?

Comment: I guess it's possible but I never tried. I think all you need is write a plugin that calls `Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput();`